# Модель для QListView с чекбоксами и текстом

Tags: c++, qt, gui

Есть `QListView`, его заполнение происходит посредством `QStandardItemModel`. Список содержит элементы, каждый из которых имеет текст и чекбокс. Нужно, чтобы при нажатии на текст срабатывал чекбокс.

```
  QStandardItemModel *model = new QStandardItemModel(SIZE_LIST, 1);
  for (int i = 0, sz = SIZE_LIST; i < sz; ++i)
  {
      QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem;
      item->setData("sometitle", Qt::EditRole);
      item->setData(NUMBER, Qt::UserRole);
      item->setFlags(Qt::ItemIsUserCheckable | Qt::ItemIsEnabled);
      item->setData(Qt::Unchecked, Qt::CheckStateRole);
      model->setItem(i,0,item);
    }
  }

listView->setModel(model);
```

При клике на текст, а не на чекбокс, элемент должен менять состояние своего чекбокса на противоположное.
Попытался таким образом: при клике на элемент в списке вызываю слот `connect(listView,SIGNAL(clicked(QModelIndex)),this,SLOT(slotCheck(QModelIndex)));`

Который меняет состояние чекбокса на противоположное. Но: сигнал `Clicked` поступает и при нажатии непосредственно на чекбокс. Таким образом, при попытке поставить галку в чекбокс она сбрасывается.

```
void MyClass::slotCheck(QModelIndex index)
{
  Qt::CheckState state = (Qt::CheckState)
index.model()->data(index,Qt::CheckStateRole).toInt();
  Qt::CheckState newstate = Qt::Checked;
  if (Qt::Checked == state)
  {
    newstate = Qt::Unchecked;
  }
  ui_->descr->model()->setData(index, QVariant(newstate), Qt::CheckStateRole);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте в качестве представления `QTreeView` вместо `QListView`. Текст первого столбца оставьте пустым, только установите свойство: `checkable = true`. Второй столбец пусть содержит необходимый вам текст.

```
QStandardItemModel* model = new QStandardItemModel();
fillModel(model);                        // заполняем модель данными
ui->treeview->setModel(model);           // связываем представление с моделью
ui->treeview->setHeaderHidden(true);     // прячем заголовки столбцов (по необходимости)
ui->treeview->resizeColumnToContents(0); // устанавливаем ширину первого столбца равной ширине checkbox'ов
// далее соединяем сигнал со слотом:
connect(ui_->treeview, SIGNAL(clicked(const QModelIndex&)), SLOT(slotClickItem(const QModelIndex&)));
```

В слоте же проверяйте, на каком столбце произошёл клик: если на первом, то чекбокс сам поменяет своё состояние, иначе - меняем его состояние "вручную".
Реализация слота:

```
void slotClickItem(const QModelIndex& index)
{
  QStandardItemModel* model = qobject_cast<QStandardItemModel*>(ui->treeview->model());
  QStandardItem* clickedItem = model->itemFromIndex(index);
  if (clickedItem->column() != 0) {
    QStandardItem* checkedItem = model->item(clickedItem->row(), 0);
    Qt::CheckState currentState = checkedItem->checkState();
    Qt::CheckState nextState = (currentState == Qt::Checked ? Qt::Unchecked : Qt::Checked);
    checkedItem->setCheckState(nextState);
  }
}
```

Метод `fillModel` замените на свой, для примера я использовал такой:

```
void fillModel(QStandardItemModel* model)
{
  QList<QStandardItem*> row;
  const int countRows = 5;
  for (int i = 0; i < countRows; ++i) {
    QStandardItem* item = new QStandardItem();
    item->setCheckable(true);
    row.append(item);

    item = new QStandardItem(QString::number(i+1));
    item->setEditable(false);
    row.append(item);
    model->appendRow(row);
    row.clear();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте использовать метод `blockSignals()` для чекбокса, таким образом у вас будет срабатывать только один сигнал от `QListView`, а сигналы от чекбокса заблокируются.

Answer (score 0):

Можно унаследовать `QListView` и переопределить защищённый метод:

```
virtual void QListView::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event);
```

Из `event` можно получить координаты клика мышью. Далее, при помощи метода:

```
virtual QModelIndex QListView::indexAt(const QPoint &p) const;
```

... получается индекс элемента, по которому был произведён щелчок. А метод:

```
virtual QRect QListView::visualRect(const QModelIndex &index) const;
```

... даст прямоугольник этого элемента. Соответственно, если принимать клики на кастомную обработку только с некоторым сдвигом от левого края (чекбокс обычно расположен слева), то можно решить поставленную задачу.

Если не устравивает "некоторый" сдвиг от края элемента, то можно обратиться к стилю через `QStyleOption` и получить точную информацию о размерах "квадратика" чекбокса.